# vue.js not working with my first test html page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to check how to vue.js javascript works.That's also not working for me.Any one like to share what is wrong with html page or what am missing here.

CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ greeting }}</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"/></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            e1: '#app',
            data: {
                greeting : 'Hello from ankit using vue.js!'
            }
        }); 
    </script>
```

Current Output of above code in chrome :

{{ greeting }}

Expecting output :

*Hello from ankit using vue.js!*

Anyone like to share what is wrong with my code ? 
Please note ,I also cleared cache from browser.

Comment: place script with the library on top

Comment: 1. Perhaps you need to add a body tag. 2. You have there e1 instead of EL -> el

Answer (score 1):

You're making a typo, you should have `el` instead of `e1`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
        <h1>{{ greeting }}</h1>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
               return{
                greeting : 'Hello from ankit using vue.js!'
               }
            }
        }); 
    </script>
```